# Guided filter in OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv

I wanted to use a guided filter on an image to compare bilateral and guided filters, but my guided filter code shows the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GuidedFilter'
```

How do I fix this error? My code is as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\Saloni\\Pictures\\p1.jpg")    
guided = cv2.GuidedFilter(img,13,70)    
cv2.imshow("image",img)    
cv2.imshow("guided filtering",guided)    
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 12):

GuidedFilter is not in core, but in the [ximgproc contrib module.](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/ximgproc)

So you'll have to make sure your OpenCV installation is built with contrib modules enabled in order to use GuidedFilter. If it's not, you might check [this link](http://tzutalin.blogspot.de/2016/01/installing-opencv-310-and-contrib-lib.html).

If contrib modules are installed you can just do

```
from cv2.ximgproc import guidedFilter
```